# performSegueWithIdentifier has no segue with identifier

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I encountered a crash while testing my app. The following image is my storyboard:

[image: storyboard]

I have the code in View Controller:

```
@IBAction func unwindToHomeScreen(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {

}
```

The view of "Add new Item" have a "Cancel" button, I controlled-drag it to the "Exit" icon at the top and link to `unwindToHomeScreen`, it works fine.

The "Add new Item" has a class `AddTableViewController` and the code I wrote inside:

```
@IBAction func save() {
    // Execute the unwind segue and go back to the home screen
    performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindToHomeScreen", sender: self)
}
```

I controlled-drag the "Save" button to the func, but the app crash when I click the button

I can use `dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` instead, but I just wonder why `performSegueWithIdentifier` can't work?

I read the code at [dropbox.com/s/hpybgg9x67rtqng/foodpinstatictable.zip?dl=0](http://dropbox.com/s/hpybgg9x67rtqng/foodpinstatictable.zip?dl=0) and try to make one and using `performSegueWithIdentifier` like this example for practicing, I didn't see the segue identifier at her, what is the difference?

Comment: Did you actually give your segue an identifier in the storyboard? The name of the function in the controller you're going back to is not an identifier.

Comment: I solved the problem, when I control-drag the "Cancel" to the "Exit" icon and link to "unwindToHomeScreen", I will get the "Unwind segue to Scene Exit Placeholder" show on the Document outline under the "Add New Item Scene", and then I get it the Identitier as "unwindToHomeScreen"

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You haven't actually given that segue an identifier. `unwindToHomeScreen` is a function that you can call; what you're looking for is your segue identifier, which is set in Interface Builder like this:

[image: Set an identifier]

In this example, I have a button wired to the next view via Interface Builder like you describe ("Interface Builder") and a button that is wired to this `IBAction` in my view controller ("Programmatically"):

```
@IBAction func goToNextView(sender: UIButton!) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier:("go", sender: self)
}
```

In any case, what you're missing is the actual identifier, which can be set in the attributes of a segue created in Interface Builder.

Comment: thanks for the detail answer, that help me to find out the problem

Comment: I assumed that `sender:` should be `sender`, which didn't work but `sender: self` did, so thanks for the example!

Answer (score 6):

Swift 4:

Sometimes we must **clean** the build folder and then try again.

Worked for me after ctrl-dragging the new segue and giving it a name, then using it programatically as:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMyNewViewController" , sender: self)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that because I renamed my view controller, I needed to delete and recreate the segue.

Answer (score 1):

A possible issue with iOS 12 and earlier (iOS 13 seems not to suffer from the same issue) might come from the fact that *performSegue(withIdentifier:,sender:) is called from the view controller viewdidLoad() callback*.

You absolutely *must invoke it from the **viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)** callback* in order to avoid the question-mentioned crash.

That will certainly save hours of hair-puling…

Answer (score 0):

in my case reorder the Embed in

Tab bar controller
   Navigation controller
       vc (contains button - tapping button initiates a "show, e.g. push" segue)

Too fix the title in the navigationBar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

All I did was:

I selected the segue indicator in the storyboard.

Deleted it.

Then created a new segue with the same identifier. Boom, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had it all wired up correctly. It was just that the viewController I was segueing from, was NOT instantiated from the storyboard. I had it instantiated pragmatically.

I initially had it written as:

```
let vc = DeviceVC()
```

Had to change it to:

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle(for: DeviceVC.self))
let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(identifier: "DeviceVC") as! DevieVC
```

Answer (score -1):

for me --> click on the relation-arrow between view controllers and then select attribute inspector, there is identifier give name and select push class done...