# (lldb) error in swift when trying to perform segue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6, segue

I was trying to make an app with a login page. When I try to perform the segue via code, the app crashes and displays the error "(lldb)". I want to be able to segue at a specific time, not just when the user taps a button. My show function is this.
`func showLogin(){
        performSegueWithIdentifier("GoToLogin", sender: self)
    }`

I call this function here.

```
if PFUser.currentUser() == nil{
        showLogin()

    }
```

That was where the error occurred. How can I perform a segue like this?

Comment: Are you sure that the identifier you have entered is *exactly* the same as the one you've given in Interface Builder? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889645/performseguewithidentifier-has-no-segue-with-identifier/27889726#27889726).

Comment: You should examine the actual error and stack trace from the crash. `(lldb)` isn't an error, it's the prompt for the [LLDB debugger](http://lldb.llvm.org). Although [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1) is based on Objective C, its advice on the basics of examining a crash in Xcode is still applicable to Swift development.